# Collapsible FAQ with links that jump to and expand other questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-jump

I currently have this code for an FAQ list of questions and answers. The headings, questions and answers are expandable/collapsible on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/7RbCZ/

However, one feature I need is to be able to, within answer text, link to other questions so that the page jumps to and opens up this question.

Currently I have written (line 6 HTML):

```
(See <a href="#question-3">Question 3</a>)
```

in the answer to Question 1, and given Question 3 an id (line 18 HTML):

```
<li class="list-level-2" id="question-3">Question 3?
```

This is not working but hopefully demonstrates what I want to achieve.

Thanks very much for any help.

Edit: Thanks to marbor3 below. Re:their solution, does any one have any ideas about how to get the page to jump to this question/answer? Also have a problem that if the question linked to is already open then the trigger(click) makes it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch `click event` on the link and `trigger click event` in element which id is in the `href`

```
$(".triggerNextQuestion").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var question = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if(!question.parent().is(':visible')) {
        question.parent().trigger('click');
    } 
    question.trigger('click');
});
```

You will need to check if parent is visible also, to show it if it's not.

It's a starting point, sure needs some modifications, like showing question in after parent is shown.

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsMhP/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! (I would vote up but don't have enough reputation points yet) Does any one have any ideas about how to get the page to jump to this question/answer? Also have a problem that if the question linked to is already open then clicking makes it invisible. I'll keep looking.